# DropDownList selected item / value not retained on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net user control with 3 DropDownLists i.e (`ddlState`, `ddlOffice` and `ddlOfficeType`)

- `ddlState` loads all states
- `ddlOffice` loads offices in the selected state
- while `ddlOfficeType` loads office types in the selected office.

In the user control file (.ascx.cs), I have the below on `Page_Load`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    //{
        PopulateStates();
        Session[PageName + "State"] = ddlState.SelectedValue;
    //}
}
```

When the state selection changes, I have that event handled as below

```
protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string previousStateSelection = null;
    if (Session["State"] != null)
    {
        previousStateSelection = Session["State"].ToString();
    }
    PopulateOffices(int.Parse(ddlState.SelectedValue));
    Session[PageName + "State"] = ddlState.SelectedValue;
}
```

Now when I select a state in the 1st DropDownList, the related offices are populated correctly with the first office in the list selected.

The issue I'm facing is that when I now change the office selection in the 2nd DropDownList such that I load the 3rd DropDownList with office types related to the selected office, my new office selection is not retained on PostBack.

It's like my `ddlOffice` DropDownList is being refreshed & reset.

In `Page_Load`, I have no other code that might be reloading the `DropDownList`.

If I uncomment my check of `IsPostBack` to the below

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    PopulateStates();
    Session[PageName + "State"] = ddlState.SelectedValue;
}
```

Then even the first `ddlState` does not load anything on PostBack, both ddlState & ddlOffice return empty.

Below is how I'm databinding the DropDownLists:

Load states (All)

```
private void PopulateStates()
{
    if (ddlState.Items.Count > 0)
        return;

    States = GetStates()
    ddlState.ClearSelection();
    ddlState.Items.Clear();
    ddlState.DataSource = States;
    ddlState.DataTextField = "State_Name";
    ddlState.DataValueField = "State_ID";
    ddlState.DataBind();
}
```

Load offices based on selected state

```
private void PopulateOffices(int stateId)
{
    var offices = new List<Office>();
    offices = GetofficesBystateId(stateId).OrderBy(s => s.OfficeName).ToList();

    ddlOffice.ClearSelection();
    ddlOffice.Items.Clear();
    ddlOffice.DataSource = offices;
    ddlOffice.DataTextField = "OfficeName";
    ddlOffice.DataValueField = "OfficeId";
    ddlOffice.DataBind();

   ddlOffice.SelectedIndex = ddlOffice.Items.IndexOf(ddlOffice.Items.FindByText(ddlOffice.Text));      
}
```

Load office types based on selected office

```
private void PopulateOfficeTypes(int officeId)
{
    var officeTypes = GetofficeTypesBySite(officeId);
    ddlOfficeType.ClearSelection();
    ddlOfficeType.Items.Clear();
    ddlOfficeType.DataSource = officeTypes;
    ddlOfficeType.DataTextField = "OfficeType";
    ddlOfficeType.DataValueField = "OfficeTypeId";
    ddlOfficeType.DataBind();
}
```

In the markup, all DropDownLists have

```
runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="true"
```

2nd DDL's SelectedIndexChanged event handler.

```
protected void ddlOffice_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateOfficeTypes(int.Parse(ddlOffice.SelectedValue));
        Session[PageName + "Office"] = selectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share with us the code of the 2nd DDL's `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler?

Comment: @PeterCsala see edit at the bottom of my original post

Comment: this is webforms, right? Is this a new application? because webforms support has been dropped.

Comment: The [list control's `Text` property](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/ListControl.cs,115e128bd6d2d105,references) simply returns the value of the selected item. By the time your code executes `ddlOffice.Items.FindByText(ddlOffice.Text)`, you've already cleared the selection, so there won't be a selected value to find. And even if there was, you'd want `FindByValue` instead of `FindByText`.